# how to change Datatable's column width

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable dynamic columns. How can i change this datatable's column's width. Width property of p:columns is not working. Do I need to override "ui-editable-column" style?

```
<p:columns value="#{myController.columns}" var="column"
                           styleClass="ui-editable-column" width="10"....
```

Comment: Isn't adding a css rule for `ui-editable-column` class feasible?

Comment: I think columns will use all the width of the table, which is all the width of the container unless you specify another width. try setting the width of the table

Comment: Can you add your datatable code here... so will get idea why it's not working ...

Comment: Yes you are right, width property not working sometimes. You don't need to override column class but Try to use style="width=10px"

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this property

> resizableColumns="true"

Normally to set column width for a datatable,we use a property of datatable resizableColumns="true" and then set width for a specific column using width="40" for a column.

It should work.